# Import CSV data and trigger column matching

Tags: php, jquery, csv, import

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this - I've found plenty of guides on importing CSV files via jQuery and/or PHP, but my problem is the next step - I need to find a way of importing CSV data (ideally with jQuery but PHP would also be fine) then starting a column matching routine so the user can define what column is what, i.e. Name/Description/Date etc.

Anyone know of any good out-the-box solutions or how to even begin?

Thanks in advance,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

You may try below steps.

- 1st form : In which need to allow only csv file.
- 2nd form : fetch
  first row(Header) of uploaded csvfile. so may get all 
            the  columns of user

Ex : user upload with column d,e,f
Your requirement need column name a,b,c

In this case you have one form in which left hand side you may show your columns with which are required validation. right hand side you may show uploaded header(d,e,f)

User have to choose a =d or a = e or a = f once user will choose all columns and submit button press then you may validate all columns and allow for submit

once your data has been submitted you have to check in your php function which column match with which column and based on that need to do operations.